# Does unique_ptr swap copy contents?

Tags: c++, swap, unique-ptr

I have a class C with multiple member variables and I'm programmig a binary heap whose elements are of the type std::unique_ptr. For the reordering of elements in the heap, I'm currently calling std::swap(x,y) where x and y are references to unique_ptr.

I'm a bit confused with the explanation of this function on cplusplus.com and therelike.

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/swap-free/

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/swap/

My question is: Do these specifications of std::swap reassign pointer addresses or do they indeed do a tedious copy of the contents in x and y every time I call std::swap?

I'm asking because I could also redesign this thing and let the heap elements be just indices. These indices refer to vector entries that store the actual content. Then, a swap in the heap would just exchange two size_t's (instead of big elements of the class C) and the thing would work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One thing to note: Not a huge fan of cplusplus. [cppreference](https://www.cppreference.com/w/) is generally much better.

Comment: Do you have pointers to your `unique_ptr`? If it's index-based you should be fine.

Comment: I don't have pointers to unique_ptr. They are getting swapped because I need to keep a certain order in the heap. Hence, when I add an element to the heap, for example, it has to be inserted into the right position in the heap. This is done by pairwise exchange of elements until the new element reaches its correct position.

Comment: If these pointers are truly "unique" in that you're not copying them all over the place, then yeah, `swap` should do what you want. It does the copying for you. All it does is swap the contents of two arbitrary things.

Comment: Sounds like you're making a sorted list container. Would any of the built-ins work for that?

Comment: Using `std::swap()` with two `std::unique_ptr`s calls `std::unique_ptr::swap()`, which swaps both the pointers and the associated deleters (another member of `std::unique_ptr` that handles destroying the managed object).   It does not destruct and reconstruct any of the managed objects.

Comment: @tadman I can't use a build in one b/c I need a decrease_key operation that is not given in any stl container.

Comment: What's a "decrease_key" operation in this context?

Comment: Oh well... It's very similar to what you would do in a Dijkstra-Algorithm. I know that efficient implementations would use lazy-deletion in the heap but it's not possible in my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::swap(x, y)` swaps the contents of variables `x` and `y`.

If `x` and `y` are `unique_ptr`s then it swaps the contents of the `unique_ptr` variables. A `unique_ptr` variable holds a pointer, not a whole object. Since the pointers were swapped, now `y` points to the address that `x` used to point to and `x` points to the address that `y` used to point to.

In other words it's the same as:

```
unique_ptr<whatever> temp = std::move(x);
x = std::move(y);
y = std::move(temp);
```

Comment: So just to be sure that I'm getting it right. The bottom line is that swap is indeed just exchanging addresses and thus, what is happening out of the box is more efficient than doing tedious copies of elements of my class C or your "whatever" thing.

Comment: It doesn't copy the `whatever` object at all, it copies `whatever*`, *just* the pointer, and whatever other implementation-specific crud `unique_ptr` has.

Comment: If your debugger permits it, have a look at what's actually inside `unique_ptr`. It's usually not much. That's all that gets "moved". In many cases it's really just a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

> Do these specifications of std::swap reassign pointer addresses

Yes.

> or do they indeed do a tedious copy of the contents in x and y every time I call std::swap?

No.

In case you did want to perform such swap, you could indirect through the pointers:

```
std::swap(*x, *y);
```